# Password Validation javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to create a very very basic profile page using Name, Email, Username, and Password. I have to have a password validation code/button.

The home page will be very similar to a common profile page. The user must be able to input the following:

- Name field
- Email field
- User ID field
- Password field 3
- Validation Password field

The following buttons are required:

- Password validation button
- Create Profile button

I can put it all together, but the problem I am having is that the javascript console is telling me that there are some errors in the code...

```js
function validate(){
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('password');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('Password2');

    if (pass1 == pass2)
    {
        alert("Passwords Match")
    }

    else
    {
        alert("Passwords Do Not Match")
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Profile Page.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Enter First and Last Name
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <br>Enter Your Email Address
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <br>Please Enter a Username
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <br>Please Enter a Password
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <br>Enter Your Password Again
    <input type="Password" id="password2">
    <br>

    <button type="button" id="validate" onClick="validate()">Validate Password</button>
    <button type="button" id="create" onClick="submit()">Create Profile</button>
</body>
```

---

Ok, so I figured out where my errors were, now the alert that I set up for the passwords not matching is coming up, even when the passwords are the same thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: ... I don't even know where to start

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I count at least 4 completely different JS errors there. Please read an introductory JavaScript tutorial. (And if that doesn't help you understand an error, then include the error message in the question!)

Comment: the console is telling me that there is a unexpected token in javascript line 1, and that the object is not a function on the validate password button. so my question is, why is it telling me that the javascript line 1 is unexpected when its a function just like all the other code ive written, and why is it telling me that the button isnt a function?

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this:

```js
function validateForm(){
    var pass1 = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementsByName("password2")[0].value;
    if (pass1 === pass2) {
        alert("Passwords Match");
    } else {
        alert("Passwords Do Not Match");
    }
}
```

```html
Enter First and Last Name
<input type = "text" id = "name" /><br/>
Enter Your Email Address
<input type = "text" id = "email" /><br/>
Please Enter a Username
<input type = "text" id = "username" /><br/>
Please Enter a Password
<input type = "password" name = "password" /><br/>
Enter Your Password Again
<input type = "Password" name= "password2" /><br/>

<button type = "button" id = "validate" onclick = "validateForm();">Validate Password</button>
<button type = "button" id = "create" onclick = "submit()">Create Profile</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the generic function to validate password by comparing with repeat password, Contains lowercase, Contains uppercase, Contains digit

```
function validatePassword(password, repeatPassword){
var MinLength = 6;
var MaxLength = 15;

var meetsLengthRequirements:boolean = password.length >= MinLength && repeatPassword.length <= MaxLength;
var hasUpperCasevarter:boolean = false;
var hasLowerCasevarter:boolean = false;
var hasDecimalDigit:boolean = false;

if (meetsLengthRequirements)
{
  for (var i = 0, len = password.length; i < len; i++) {
    var char = password.charAt(i);
    if (!isNaN( +char * 1)){
      hasDecimalDigit = true;
    }
    else{
      if (char == char.toUpperCase()) {
        hasUpperCasevarter = true;
      }
      if (char == char.toLowerCase()){
        hasLowerCasevarter = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

var isValid = meetsLengthRequirements
            && hasUpperCasevarter
            && hasLowerCasevarter
            && hasDecimalDigit;
return isValid;
}
```